# Save hash in the csv ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I have hash:

```
users = {
'name' => name,
        'last_name' => last_name,
        'photo' => photo,
        'address' => address,
}
```

Save in csv:

```
CSV.open("users.csv", "a") {|csv| users.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem}}
```

Output:

```
 name, Jake
 last_name,Kallen
photo, http://avs.ru/leto_3434.jpg
address, NEW YORK
name, Dan
 last_name,Leans
photo, http://avs.ru/leto_3423.jpg
address, NEW YORK
```

I need to get the file:

```
Jake,Kallen,http://avs.ru/leto_3434.jpg,NEW YORK
```

How to change my code to get what I need? 
Help me please.

UPD: I forgot to point out that a lot of users

Comment: Besides the output issue: is `users` really a single hash? The name (`users`, plural) and your use case suggests that it should be an array (of hashes).

Comment: UPD: Yes, thank you
I forgot to point out that a lot of users

Comment: Would you mind to update your question accordingly?

Comment: Please show some effort and update your question's code. `users` is still a single hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CSV.open("users.csv", "a") {|csv|
  csv << users.values
}
```

I think, you need this. If `users` hash will contains other data - csv will take it to

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
CSV.open("users.csv", "a") do |csv|
  csv << users.values_at('name', 'last_name', 'photo', 'address')
end
```

You want to extract the hash values by key and pass it to the csv object as an array, which values_at returns.

If you have more than one user, please update the sample data in your question.